# Trying to copy data from cell A4:U of all sheets apart from 'Master', 'Index' and 'Tracker Template' to where column A shows 'Totals'

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, I'm trying to create a VBA but really struggling to find how I would create the dynamic range where it searches every possible sheet and copies them into the master from A4:U(wherever the first word that says totals is). I also want to ensure there are no blank rows being copied across and the data doesn't duplicate when I do this. Is this possible?

I have tried to write the code, using other examples but I'm relatively new to building macro's so haven't fully understood it all.

```vb
    Sub CopySheetsToMaster()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i, LastRowa, LastRowd As Long
    Dim WSname As String
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    
    If ws.Name = "Master" or "Index or "Tracker Template" Then
    
    WSname = ws.Name
    
    LastRowa = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowd = Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ws.Range("A4:Q" & LastRowa).Copy
    Sheets("Master").Range("A" & LastRowd + 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Master").Range("A" & LastRowd + 1).Value = WSname
    
    End If
    
    Next ws
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Hey, I've just added the code. It wouldn't let me add this first time around

Comment: You need closing `"` round index, but you need to say `ws.name=x or ws.name=y`

Comment: Yeah, apologies I deleted that by mistake after copying. Where do I put the ws.name=x or ws.name=y? What does it do?

Comment: `ws.Name = "Master" or ws.name ="Index" or ws.name "Tracker Template" Then`

Comment: Is the copied range `A4:U(wherever the first word that says totals is)` or `"A4:Q" & LastRowa` ?